# Linux cURL to Windows cURL in bat file

Tags: linux, windows, bash, batch-file, curl

I have been trying for a few days to figure out how to convert a cURL command that works perfectly in the Linux terminal but just can't figure out how to format it correctly so that I can use it in a windows bat file. Any help would be highly appreciated.

The Linux cURL command that works perfectly in Linux:

```
curl -X PUT \
-H 'Accept:application/json; charset=utf-8' \
-H 'Content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8' \
http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/testlive/pushpublish/mapentries/ppsource \
-d'
{
   "serverName": "_defaultServer_",
   "sourceStreamName": "newStream",
   "entryName": "ppsource",
   "profile": "rtmp",
   "host": "localhost",
   "application": "testlive",
   "userName": "testUser",
   "password": "pass",
   "streamName": "myStream"
}'
```

How can I do the same in windows cmd?

Answer (score 3):

- Change single quotes to double quotes
- Change the line continuation character from `\` to `^`
- Check the effective command with `echo on`

Or use a browser (using windows), open the developer mode (F12) and copy a network entry with `copy as windows curl`

If a line contains only a single or an odd number of quotes, the last quote has to be escaped, that ensures the caret at the line end still works.

Ex.

```
echo on

curl -X PUT ^
-H 'Accept:application/json; charset=utf-8' ^
-H 'Content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8' ^
http://localhost:8087/v2/^    
-d^"^
{^
 "serverName": "_defaultServer_",^
```

Comment: @user2956477 @jeb thanks for the reply. I replaced the \ with ^ and `'` with `"`. When i run the bat file, it considers the first word of each new line after `-d"` as a command and so shows the following error `'{' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @user3191135 You should add your attempt in your question. Use `echo on` in your batch file to see how the lines are interpreted. Probably you try `-d"^`  this fails, because the caret doesn't work there,  the quote *escapes* all characters up to the end of the line

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I managed to figure it out with the suggestions from others on here and a few other websites.

```
curl -X PUT ^
-H "Accept:application/json; charset=utf-8" ^
-H "Content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8" ^
"http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/testlive/pushpublish/mapentries/ppsource" -d "{^
\"serverName\": \"_defaultServer_\",^
\"sourceStreamName\": \"newStream\",^
\"entryName\": \"ppsource\",^
\"profile\": \"rtmp\",^
\"host\": \"localhost\",^
\"application\": \"testlive\",^
\"userName\": \"\",^
\"password\": \"\",^
\"streamName\": \"myStream\"^
}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use carret `^` as a line continuation symbol instead of backslash `\`, and doublequote all string instead of singlequoute. Include line termination to json at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to above ( a little bit out of scope, yet, if it helps someone ) :

cURL online converters ( e.g https://curlconverter.com/ ) might assist you with the above.